# Return "instances of" property for a wikidata item using SPARQL

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I have a list of wikidata items I wish to extract the "instance of" property from. For example, looking up [Q1339](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q1339) I can see that it has a single instance type (P:31) labelled "human" (Q5). I have tried to write a simple query that would extract that but I am not getting any records returned. I am v. new to SPARQL so it's very likely I'm missing something obvious.

```
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel
WHERE
{
  ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q1339.
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE]". }
}
```

Comment: With this query, you are asking for an instance of `wd:Q1339` , JS Bach. `wd:Q1339` is an instance of human. So in all cases, the object of a triple pattern needs to be a (de facto) class of things like human, person, place, work etc. Yet have in mind that Wikdata there is no clear difference between instance and class, they are both just items.

Comment: if you look up `Q1339` and see "instance of" relations this means it is the subject of the triple. Just switch subject and object in your query. Yes, in RDF direction matters

Comment: Thanks @UninformedUser - that did the trick.